# How to test disabled or inactive element in a drop down or list using selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

In my application, with respect to user access some elements in drop down will be enabled/disabled.I have to check whether the particular element is disabled or not.

Answer (score 3):

If the element you're trying to find has a literal "disabled" attribute you're probably looking for `someElement.isEnabled()` which would return a boolean based on the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use XPath to identify the disabled elements in dropdown

Ex:- `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//option[@disabled="disabled"]"))`

Comment: The above code works perfectly

Comment: Cheers...........